# Orphaned package etiquette

Tags: r, package

I just-now noticed that a package I use has been "orphaned", meaning it no longer has an active maintainer.  The reasons this can happen are (from [this document](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Orphaned/README)):

> 1) The current maintainer actively wants to orphanize the package,
>   e.g., due to no longer having time or interest to act as package
>   maintainer.
>
> 2) Emails sent to the current maintainer by the CRAN admins bounced,
>   or    were not answered for longer periods of time.

The same document also reads (emphasis added):

> Everybody is more than welcome to take over as maintainer of an
>   orphaned package.  ***Simply*** download the package sources, make
>   changes if necessary (respecting original author and license!) and
>   ***resubmit the package to CRAN with your name as maintainer in the DESCRIPTION file of the package***.

I find this package useful, and would hate to see it archived because it fails `R CMD CHECK` in the future, so here are my questions:

- What is the general attitude towards assuming "maintainer" status of
  an orphaned package?
- What if reason (2) is the culprit, but the last maintainer still
          wants the responsibility and *[insert hypothetical situation]*?
- Are there any examples of this situation I can take a look at?

Comment: What package are you talking about? Have you tried to contact the maintainer? What is the license of this package? Why don't you do as the CRAN instruction say and submit a new version that passes `R CMD check`?

Comment: Mainly `sapa`, but the same maintainer apparently orphaned all other packages he had, many of which `sapa` depends on.  I would rather re-bundle the orphaned dependencies with `sapa`, but I've never had to deal with licensing issues (`sapa` uses GPL2). Trying not to step on any toes, so to speak.

Comment: OK, so it's GPL2. That means you can modify and re-publish under the GPL2 license. Have you contacted the author and offered to help?

Comment: No, I haven't.  At this point neither `sapa` nor any of it's dependencies have been archived.  I'm just trying to understand what the politically correct process would be if it becomes necessary.

Comment: For `sapa`, I think the maintainer might be this guy http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?&id=22547699 who is obviously still involved with R.

Comment: I think the Rcpp package was orphaned by a previous maintainer before Dirk and Romain took it over.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The first step is to contact the current maintainer and offer to help. Speaking from my own experience, package maintainers are grateful to know that there is at least one other person who values their work, and gladly accept offers to help maintain an ageing code base.

If you don't get a response from the current maintainer, then I suggest you assume the mantle and submit an updated version to CRAN. CRAN have policies for these events, and will still try to contact the previous maintainer.

In the unlikely event that the current maintainer doesn't want to co-operate, then you have the option of forking the package and create your own version.

Comment: Well put.  A follow up question: How long should one wait after contacting (assuming no reply) to proceed?

Comment: How long is a piece of string? I don't know, a week? In the case of `sapa`, the original maintainer is `William Constantine <wconstan@insightful.com>` - I know this from the archived DESCRIPTION files on CRAN.  But, as @richiecotton said, he is now most probably employed elsewhere. You can possibly also contact the book author to ask about intentions to maintain the package.

Comment: If the package is orphaned, it usually means that the author has been unresponsive to CRAN for at least a couple of months. It may be that the email address in the `DESCRIPTION` is incorrect, so doing some research on the author's current email address might be the best place to start.

Answer (score 8):

Andrie's answer mentions contacting the current maintainer. While it is absolutely correct, it falls a bit short in that in many cases, the reason why the package is orphaned by CRAN is precisely due to a broken email address and nothing more. Therefore the lack of answer from the package maintainer is no proof at all that he is not interested in his package any longer.
See all the `BOUNCE` (many .edu/.ac are disabled when the person changes institution) and `NOREPLY` (mailbox not checked any longer by the maintainer) lines in [the list of orphaned packages](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Orphaned/PACKAGES.csv).

Some comments hint towards this direction: you probably want to put more effort into contacting the previous maintainer than Andrie's answer suggests. I would suggest the following:

- Try to research for a new address or contact point on social networks (LinkedIn, ResearchGate, etc.), especially around R (R-help mailing list, or even SO / CrossValidated)
- In the case of an academic author, try to find a recent paper that could mention a new institution and give you a good starting point.
- There could be an other package maintained by the same person but with an other email address that is still working
- Collaborators (especially co-authors of the package) probably know how to contact the maintainer and will likely help you with that. In the case of `sapa`, you could have contacted Donald Percival. Had he not taken the maintainer role himself, (he now appears to be the maintainer of the package), it is most likely he would have given you up-to-date contact information, or contacted the old maintainer himself (and since the request comes from a "trusted" party, it would have been most likely to succeed). In other cases, co-authors from other papers can help you as well.

Only if all this fails should you proceed with becoming the maintainer yourself as described in Andrie's answer.

As an example, package of mine was orphaned in the past, because an old institutional email address was disabled some time after I left the university. I knew it would be disabled, but I totally failed to realize it would impact my package.
I realized the package was orphaned as I was preparing to submit an update. Luckily enough, no one took it over during this period, but I would have hated it if someone had.

Email address changes are common in professional and academic environments, so keep in mind the maintainer is likely just not aware that his package has been orphaned.

Comment: CRAN are unwilling to make any effort to track down authors once their e-mail breaks (this is arguably a legitimate stance). Hopefully a quick web search would be able to locate the author, and more extreme measures wouldn't be needed (although admittedly an hour of searching is not much relative to the effort of adopting a package)

Answer (score 3):

Re **sapa** package: I had a `NAMESPACE` issue calling it from the **ForeCA** package.  For a successful (no headache) CRAN submission I ended up contacting the owner of **sapa**, Don Percival, and basically emailed him a fixed package (just a couple of lines of fixed `Imports`/`Depends` statements).

He was very helpful to get the new version out asap, and it is [now on CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sapa/index.html) (version `2.0-1`) passing all [CRAN checks](http://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_sapa.html).